# Struggling with Peskin and Schroeder equation (12.49) and the constraint of renormalizability

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, greens-functions, correlation-functions, propagator

In peskin and schroeder it's written that any renormalizable massless scalar field theory has a 2-point greens function of the form:

[image: 12.49 from peskin and schroeder]

I don't get how we can know that the 1-loop diagrams have exactly this kind divergence.
I understand it for massless QED and for $\phi^4$ theory but couldnt a general renormalizable massless scalar theory involve some exotic contributions?
I think my problem is that I don't understand the extent of these constraints (renormalizability).
For example I don't know why there shouldn't be a coupling to something like a vector or tensor field.

Comment: The lack of vectors and tensors is assumed. By scalar field theory, they just mean adding $V(\phi) = \sum_n g_n \phi^n$ potentials to the free theory. If $d \geq 3$, you can count how many of them are renormalizable on one hand.